# CircularImage Library inflate error Android

Tags: android

I am using CircularImageView Library in my Activity but showing error while inflating.As the library is added with no error during gradle sync.I added this library to get rounded shadow around circle bitmap

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/panelIconLeft"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp" >


            </LinearLayout>
            <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_Customer_Details"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:src="@drawable/m128"

                />
              </RelativeLayout>
```

Activity :

```
   setContentView(R.layout.customer_detail);
   customer_name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cust_name);
   image=(CircularImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_Customer_Details);
```

Error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{loginscreen.example.com.girviapp/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp.Customer_Detail}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at loginscreen.example.com.girviapp.Customer_Detail.onCreate(Customer_Detail.java:44)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at loginscreen.example.com.girviapp.Customer_Detail.onCreate(Customer_Detail.java:44)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/mikhaellopez/circularimageview/R$attr;
            at com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView.<init>(CircularImageView.java:28)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at loginscreen.example.com.girviapp.Customer_Detail.onCreate(Customer_Detail.java:44)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.R$attr" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView.<init>(CircularImageView.java:28)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at loginscreen.example.com.girviapp.Customer_Detail.onCreate(Customer_Detail.java:44)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.R$attr
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 28 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: Please provide any solution

Comment: Got stucked help needed

Answer (score 0):

check out if there is suitable construtor for instantial of this view.
public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)